# CSS issue with responsive grid layout using percentages

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a responsive layout made up of a grid of boxes, of which there are two types. The first box 'type' contains just an image within second div, and a second box 'type' that is half the width of the first but it also contains two smaller images, one stacked on top of the other.

I'm having a weird issue where occasionally some of the boxes drop below and then jump back.  This only seems to happen when I mix both types of boxes, if I replace all the second box types with the first type (and vice versa), there's no issue!

Here's a jsfiddle, if you resize your browser window you will see the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/DZ7jD/

And here's a snippet of my code:

First box type:

```
<div class="item">
    <div>
        <img src="myimage.jpg" />
    </div>      
</div>
```

Second box type:

```
<div class="item stacked">
    <div class="item top">
        <div>
            <img src="myimage.jpg" />
        </div>      
    </div>              
    <div class="item bottom">
        <div>
            <img src="myimage.jpg" />
        </div>      
    </div>                  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else with a similar issue I managed to fix this with jQuery. There seemed to be an issue with heights of my 'stacked' class so I made this script so that the heights of every box are always the same:

```
$(document).ready(FixHeights);
$(window).resize(FixHeights);

function FixHeights(){
    var $x = $(".container > .item").not(".stacked").first().width();
    $(".container > .item").height($x + "px");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use display: `inline-block;` with `vertical-align: top;` on the `.item`.

```
.item{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width:20%;
}
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/verber/DZ7jD/5/

IE7 nad IE8 does not understand `display: inline-block;` property, you should use the native `display: inline;` with `zoom: 1;`. And the `*` symbol will make it visible only for IE browsers:

```
display: inline-block;
*zoom: 1;
*display: inline;
```

**DEMO for IE7+**: http://jsfiddle.net/verber/DZ7jD/21/

Comment: hey andrey, thanks for the help! do you know how I could get it to work using floats?

Comment: Updated upper comment

Answer (score 0):

A clear should stop the jumping.

I've added a clear div after the first row of images.

```
.clear {clear: both;}
```

See updated: http://jsfiddle.net/DZ7jD/2/